# How to move to elements higher next to central division (column-md-8)?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to move the Calendar-division and Notities-division more upwards. But I can't seem to figure it out without ruining the layout.

What I tried:

moving the calendar division one division below that of the Waarschuwing-division. This way the calendar division goes to the place I want it to. But this creates a rather big gap between the Legend division and the client-list division.

this is what I am trying to do:

[image]

my code:

```
<?php
include('session.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bravo Portal</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="Bootply" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Responsive slider -->
    <link href="css/responsive-calendar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style type="text/css">

    table.scroll {
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

table.scroll th,
table.scroll td,
table.scroll tr,
table.scroll thead,
table.scroll tbody { display: block; }

table.scroll thead tr {
    /* fallback */
    width: 97%;
    /* minus scroll bar width */
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 16px);
    width:    -moz-calc(100% - 16px);
    width:         calc(100% - 16px);
}

table.scroll tr:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
}

table.scroll tbody {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

table.scroll tbody td,
table.scroll thead th {
    width: 19%;
    float: left;
    border-right: 0px solid grey;
}

thead tr th { 
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /*text-align: left;*/
}

 table td.green{
        background: green;
    }

    table td.red{
        background: red;
    }

    table td.orange{
        background: orange;
    }

tbody { border-top: 2px solid black; padding-bottom: 50%; }

tbody td:last-child, thead th:last-child {
    border-right: none !important;
}

#hoverTable{
        width:100%; 
        border-collapse:collapse; 
    }
    #hoverTable td{ 

    }
    /* Define the default color for all the table rows */
    #hoverTable tr{

    }
    /* Define the hover highlight color for the table row */
    #hoverTable tr:hover {
          background-color: #ffff99;
    }

.my-legend .legend-title {
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 90%;
    }
  .my-legend .legend-scale ul {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    }
  .my-legend .legend-scale ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 80%;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 18px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    }
  .my-legend ul.legend-labels li span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    width: 20px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    }

  .my-legend a {
    color: #777;
    }

/*notities*/


@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400);

/* body {
font: normal normal 13px/16px "Open Sans", sans-serif;
background: #ccc;
} */

.contain{
width: 300px;
border-radius: 3px;
}

form {
display: inline-block;
}

input{
padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}

#button1{
display: inline-block;
background-color:#fc999b;
color:#ffffff;
border-radius: 1px;
text-align:center;
margin-top:1px;
padding: 3px 3px;
}

#button1:hover{
cursor: pointer;
opacity: .8;}

ol {padding-left: 20px;}
ol li {padding: 5px;color:#000;}
ol li:nth-child(even){background: #70ABAF;}
.strike{text-decoration: line-through;}
li:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
 }
/*notities*/
a{
  color: black;
}

</style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #70ABAF;">

<!-- BEGIN HEADER -->
<header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="banner" style="background-color: #32292F; color: #99E1D9;">

<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Bravo Portal</a>
  </div>
  <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
        <a href="portal.php">Hoofdpagina</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="patients.php">Cliënten</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div align="right" style="padding-top: 1%;">
<b id="welcome">Welkom: <i style="color: #ADADFF;"><?php echo $login_session; ?></i></b>
<b id="logout"><a href="../logout.php">Uitloggen</a></b>
</div>
  </nav>
</div>
</header>
<!-- END HEADER -->


<div class="container">
<div class="row">


<!-- WAARSCHUWWING -->
<div class="col-md-8" style="border-style: solid; color: #99E1D9;">
<div style=" padding-top: 2%; padding-bottom: 2%;">WAARSCHUWINGEN<small class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-1x fa-fw" style="color: #705D56;"></small></div>
<!-- <hr style="padding: 0%; margin: 0%;"> -->

<!-- Begin Gevallen -->
  <div class="col-md-6" style="color: #705D56; margin-bottom: 0%; padding-bottom: 0%;">
  <p>Rode Status Geval</p>
  </div>  
  <div class="col-md-6" style="color: #705D56;">
  <p>Oranje Status Geval</p>
  </div> 
  <!-- End Gevallen -->

<!-- Show Record -->
<div style="height:90px; overflow:auto; margin-bottom: 1%; border: solid 0px #705D56; padding-top: 0%; margin-top: 0%;" class="col-md-6">
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "patientdb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT naam FROM clients WHERE status > '60'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<a href='patients.php'>";
        echo "" . $row["naam"]."</a><br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
</div>

<!-- Show Record -->
<div style="height:90px; overflow:auto; margin-bottom: 1%; border: solid 0px #705D56;" class="col-md-6">
<!-- show records -->
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "patientdb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT naam FROM clients WHERE status > '58' AND status < '60'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<a href='patients.php'>";
        echo "" . $row["naam"]."</a><br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
</div>
<!-- end show record -->

</div>
<!--END WAARSCHUWING -->

<!-- BEGIN LEGEND -->
<div class='my-legend' style="clear: both; padding-top: 0%; margin-top: 0%;">
<div class='legend-scale'>
  <ul class='legend-labels'>
<li><span style='background:green;'></span></li>
<li>Goed</li>
<li><span style='background:yellow;'></span></li>
<li>Minder goed</li>
<li><span style='background:orange;'></span></li>
<li>Matig</li>
<li><span style='background:red;'></span></li>
<li>Slecht</li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
<!-- END LEGEND -->

<!-- BEGIN CLIENT LIST -->
<div class="col-md-8" style=" padding-top: 2%; padding-left: 0%; clear: both;">            
<h4 style="color: #99E1D9;"> Cliënten Lijst</h4>
<!-- Begin Scroll List -->
<div>

<table class="scroll">
    <thead style="background-color: #99E1D9; color: #705D56;">
        <tr>
           <th>ID</th>
            <th>Naam Client</th>
            <th>Laatste Update</th>
            <th style="margin-left: 21%; padding-left: 0%;">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="hoverTable" style="font-size: 11pt;">
<?php
    //connect ot database
    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
     mysql_select_db('patientdb');

     //get data from data base for the first three columns in the table.
    $query = "SELECT id, naam, datum, status FROM clients";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    //fetch results per row into the table.
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Loop through results
    echo "<tr> 

            <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td> 
            <td>" . $row['naam'] . "</td> 
            <td>" . $row['datum'] . "</td>

            <td style='padding-left: 20%;'>";     
                // check of the data from 'status' per condition and assign it a color.
                if ($row['status'] > 60 && $row['status'] < 70) {
                    echo "<p class='fa fa-circle' style='color: red;''></p>";
                } elseif ($row['status'] > 58 && $row['status'] < 60) { 
                    echo "<p class='fa fa-circle' style='color: orange;''></p>";
                } elseif ($row['status'] > 55 && $row['status'] < 57) {
                    echo "<p class='fa fa-circle' style='color: yellow;''></p>";
                } else{
                    echo "<p class='fa fa-circle' style='color: green;''></p>";
                }
                echo "</td>

         </tr>"; 
    }
    //close database connection
    mysql_close(); 
?>

    </tbody>
</table>

</div>
<!-- End Scroll List -->

</div>
<!-- END BEGIN CLIENT LIST -->


<!-- BEGIN CALENDER -->
<div class="col-md-3" style="padding-left: 4%; padding-top: 0%; padding-bottom: 0%; margin-top: 0%;" >

<div class="responsive-calendar">
        <div class="controls">
            <a class="pull-left" data-go="prev"><div class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #705D56; color: #99E1D9; "><</div></a>
            <h4><span data-head-year></span> <span data-head-month></span></h4>
            <a class="pull-right" data-go="next"><div class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #705D56; color: #99E1D9;">></div></a>
        </div><hr/>
        <div class="day-headers">
          <div class="day header">Ma</div>
          <div class="day header">Di</div>
          <div class="day header">Wo</div>
          <div class="day header">Do</div>
          <div class="day header">Vr</div>
          <div class="day header">Za</div>
          <div class="day header">Zo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="days" data-group="days">
        </div>
      </div>
<div>
<!-- END CALENDER -->

<!-- BEGIN Notities -->
<div class="contain" class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4%;">
        <h5 style="color: #99E1D9;">Notities</h5>
    <p><em></em></p>
        <form name="toDoList">
            <input type="text" name="ListItem"/>
        </form>
        <div style="background-color: #705D56;" id="button1">voeg toe</div>
        <br/>
        <div style="height: 70px; width: 77%; overflow: auto; border: solid 1px #99E1D9;" >
        <ol></ol>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- END Notities -->

</div>
</div>

<!-- script references -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Notities -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('#button1').click(
            function(){
                var toAdd = $('input[name=ListItem]').val();
                 $('ol').append('<li style="list-style-type:square">' + toAdd + '</li>');
            });

       $("input[name=ListItem]").keyup(function(event){
          if(event.keyCode == 13){
            $("#button1").click();
          }         
      });

      $(document).on('dblclick','li', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('strike').fadeOut('slow');    
      });

      $('input').focus(function() {
        $(this).val('');
      });

      $('ol').sortable();  

    }
);
    </script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/responsive-calendar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
          time: '2017-01',
          events: {
            "2017-01-11": {"number": 5, "url": "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?pli=1#main_7"},
            "2017-01-26": {"number": 1, "url": "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?pli=1#main_7"}, 
            "2017-02-03":{"number": 1}, 
            "2017-02-12": {}}
        });
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On the first overview on the code I see a lot of paddings with % added to the `cols`, in Bootstrap is NOT recommended to do something like this because Is really hard to match the columns then. I would restructure again the grid.

Comment: @Benzay I didn't want to overshadow the kalender with the yellow-arrow. But I meant to describe that the yellow box needs to still be under the kalender but higher.

Comment: @Troyer I am very new to all this, literally learning as I go.

Comment: you need to look at this, I think you don't understand 100% the grid system :) https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you have this:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
 The things you want on the left.
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
 The things you want on the left.
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  The things you want on the right-top.
</div>
```

What happens? The content you are trying to add to the right is added when it can do it, in this case is on the last `col-md-8`.

I would wrapp your two `col-md-8` with a main `col-md-8` and make them `col-md-12`, and remove the padding with a `row`, and your right content, actually is `col-md-3` make it `col-md-4` to fit it all the cols something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12"></div>
   <div class="col-md-12"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  ...
</div>
```

I make a Bootply for you, so you can check it: http://www.bootply.com/iGCQCuU7Ip

Remove the top paddings and the things to leave the content like you want.

Comment: This worked! thanks brother. My issue was that I just learned bootstrap and had a wrong understanding of the col-md-12. The bootply sample really gave me a good perspective on your elaboration, thank you for the efforts!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution - you need to include 3 divs in a row (along with their resizing - look at code below), then open new `row` to make all of next sections below these 3 ones

```html
<div class="row">
<!-- WAARSCHUWWING -->
  <div class="col-md-8" style="border-style: solid; color: #99E1D9;">
     <div style=" padding-top: 2%; padding-bottom: 2%;">WAARSCHUWINGEN<small class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-1x fa-fw" style="color: #705D56;"></small></div>
<!-- <hr style="padding: 0%; margin: 0%;"> -->
<!-- Begin Gevallen -->
  <div class="col-md-4" style="color: #705D56; margin-bottom: 0%; padding-bottom: 0%;">
  <p>Rode Status Geval</p>
  </div>  
  <div class="col-md-4 pull-right" style="color: #705D56;">
  <p>Oranje Status Geval</p>
  </div> 
  <!-- End Gevallen -->
</div> <!-- close row -->

<div class="row">  <!-- open new row -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer..

**Just copy and past this code..**

```
<?php
include('session.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bravo Portal</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="Bootply" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Responsive slider -->
    <link href="css/responsive-calendar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style type="text/css">

    table.scroll {
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

table.scroll th,
table.scroll td,
table.scroll tr,
table.scroll thead,
table.scroll tbody { display: block; }

table.scroll thead tr {
    /* fallback */
    width: 97%;
    /* minus scroll bar width */
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 16px);
    width:    -moz-calc(100% - 16px);
    width:         calc(100% - 16px);
}

table.scroll tr:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
}

table.scroll tbody {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

table.scroll tbody td,
table.scroll thead th {
    width: 19%;
    float: left;
    border-right: 0px solid grey;
}

thead tr th { 
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /*text-align: left;*/
}

 table td.green{
        background: green;
    }

    table td.red{
        background: red;
    }

    table td.orange{
        background: orange;
    }

tbody { border-top: 2px solid black; padding-bottom: 50%; }

tbody td:last-child, thead th:last-child {
    border-right: none !important;
}

#hoverTable{
        width:100%; 
        border-collapse:collapse; 
    }
    #hoverTable td{ 

    }
    /* Define the default color for all the table rows */
    #hoverTable tr{

    }
    /* Define the hover highlight color for the table row */
    #hoverTable tr:hover {
          background-color: #ffff99;
    }

.my-legend .legend-title {
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 90%;
    }
  .my-legend .legend-scale ul {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    }
  .my-legend .legend-scale ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 80%;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 18px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    }
  .my-legend ul.legend-labels li span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    width: 20px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    }

  .my-legend a {
    color: #777;
    }

/*notities*/


@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400);

/* body {
font: normal normal 13px/16px "Open Sans", sans-serif;
background: #ccc;
} */

.contain{
width: 300px;
border-radius: 3px;
}

form {
display: inline-block;
}

input{
padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}

#button1{
display: inline-block;
background-color:#fc999b;
color:#ffffff;
border-radius: 1px;
text-align:center;
margin-top:1px;
padding: 3px 3px;
}

#button1:hover{
cursor: pointer;
opacity: .8;}

ol {padding-left: 20px;}
ol li {padding: 5px;color:#000;}
ol li:nth-child(even){background: #70ABAF;}
.strike{text-decoration: line-through;}
li:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
 }
/*notities*/
a{
  color: black;
}

</style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #70ABAF;">

<!-- BEGIN HEADER -->
<header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="banner" style="background-color: #32292F; color: #99E1D9;">

<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Bravo Portal</a>
  </div>
  <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
        <a href="portal.php">Hoofdpagina</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="patients.php">Cliënten</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div align="right" style="padding-top: 1%;">
<b id="welcome">Welkom: <i style="color: #ADADFF;"><?php echo $login_session; ?></i></b>
<b id="logout"><a href="../logout.php">Uitloggen</a></b>
</div>
  </nav>
</div>
</header>
<!-- END HEADER -->


<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<!-- BEGIN CALENDER -->
<div class="col-md-3" style="padding-left: 4%; padding-top: 0%; padding-bottom: 0%; margin-top: 0%;float: right;" >

<div class="responsive-calendar">
        <div class="controls">
            <a class="pull-left" data-go="prev"><div class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #705D56; color: #99E1D9; "><</div></a>
            <h4><span data-head-year></span> <span data-head-month></span></h4>
            <a class="pull-right" data-go="next"><div class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #705D56; color: #99E1D9;">></div></a>
        </div><hr/>
        <div class="day-headers">
          <div class="day header">Ma</div>
          <div class="day header">Di</div>
          <div class="day header">Wo</div>
          <div class="day header">Do</div>
          <div class="day header">Vr</div>
          <div class="day header">Za</div>
          <div class="day header">Zo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="days" data-group="days">
        </div>
      </div>
<div>
<!-- END CALENDER -->

<!-- BEGIN Notities -->
<div class="contain" class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4%;">
        <h5 style="color: #99E1D9;">Notities</h5>
    <p><em></em></p>
        <form name="toDoList">
            <input type="text" name="ListItem"/>
        </form>
        <div style="background-color: #705D56;" id="button1">voeg toe</div>
        <br/>
        <div style="height: 70px; width: 77%; overflow: auto; border: solid 1px #99E1D9;" >
        <ol></ol>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- END Notities -->

</div>
</div>
<!-- WAARSCHUWWING -->
<div class="col-md-8" style="border-style: solid; color: #99E1D9;">
<div style=" padding-top: 2%; padding-bottom: 2%;">WAARSCHUWINGEN<small class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-1x fa-fw" style="color: #705D56;"></small></div>
<!-- <hr style="padding: 0%; margin: 0%;"> -->

<!-- Begin Gevallen -->
  <div class="col-md-6" style="color: #705D56; margin-bottom: 0%; padding-bottom: 0%;">
  <p>Rode Status Geval</p>
  </div>  
  <div class="col-md-6" style="color: #705D56;">
  <p>Oranje Status Geval</p>
  </div> 
  <!-- End Gevallen -->

<!-- Show Record -->
<div style="height:90px; overflow:auto; margin-bottom: 1%; border: solid 0px #705D56; padding-top: 0%; margin-top: 0%;" class="col-md-6">
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "patientdb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT naam FROM clients WHERE status > '60'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<a href='patients.php'>";
        echo "" . $row["naam"]."</a><br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
</div>

<!-- Show Record -->
<div style="height:90px; overflow:auto; margin-bottom: 1%; border: solid 0px #705D56;" class="col-md-6">
<!-- show records -->
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "patientdb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT naam FROM clients WHERE status > '58' AND status < '60'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<a href='patients.php'>";
        echo "" . $row["naam"]."</a><br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
</div>
<!-- end show record -->

</div>
<!--END WAARSCHUWING -->

<!-- BEGIN LEGEND -->
<div class='my-legend' style="padding-top: 0%; margin-top: 0%;">
<div class='legend-scale'>
  <ul class='legend-labels'>
<li><span style='background:green;'></span></li>
<li>Goed</li>
<li><span style='background:yellow;'></span></li>
<li>Minder goed</li>
<li><span style='background:orange;'></span></li>
<li>Matig</li>
<li><span style='background:red;'></span></li>
<li>Slecht</li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
<!-- END LEGEND -->

<!-- BEGIN CLIENT LIST -->
<div class="col-md-8" style=" padding-top: 2%; padding-left: 0%;">            
<h4 style="color: #99E1D9;"> Cliënten Lijst</h4>
<!-- Begin Scroll List -->
<div>

<table class="scroll">
    <thead style="background-color: #99E1D9; color: #705D56;">
        <tr>
           <th>ID</th>
            <th>Naam Client</th>
            <th>Laatste Update</th>
            <th style="margin-left: 21%; padding-left: 0%;">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="hoverTable" style="font-size: 11pt;">
<?php
    //connect ot database
    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
     mysql_select_db('patientdb');

     //get data from data base for the first three columns in the table.
    $query = "SELECT id, naam, datum, status FROM clients";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    //fetch results per row into the table.
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Loop through results
    echo "<tr> 

            <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td> 
            <td>" . $row['naam'] . "</td> 
            <td>" . $row['datum'] . "</td>

            <td style='padding-left: 20%;'>";     
                // check of the data from 'status' per condition and assign it a color.
                if ($row['status'] > 60 && $row['status'] < 70) {
                    echo "<p class='fa fa-circle' style='color: red;''></p>";
                } elseif ($row['status'] > 58 && $row['status'] < 60) { 
                    echo "<p class='fa fa-circle' style='color: orange;''></p>";
                } elseif ($row['status'] > 55 && $row['status'] < 57) {
                    echo "<p class='fa fa-circle' style='color: yellow;''></p>";
                } else{
                    echo "<p class='fa fa-circle' style='color: green;''></p>";
                }
                echo "</td>

         </tr>"; 
    }
    //close database connection
    mysql_close(); 
?>

    </tbody>
</table>

</div>
<!-- End Scroll List -->

</div>
<!-- END BEGIN CLIENT LIST -->




<!-- script references -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Notities -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('#button1').click(
            function(){
                var toAdd = $('input[name=ListItem]').val();
                 $('ol').append('<li style="list-style-type:square">' + toAdd + '</li>');
            });

       $("input[name=ListItem]").keyup(function(event){
          if(event.keyCode == 13){
            $("#button1").click();
          }         
      });

      $(document).on('dblclick','li', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('strike').fadeOut('slow');    
      });

      $('input').focus(function() {
        $(this).val('');
      });

      $('ol').sortable();  

    }
);
    </script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/responsive-calendar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
          time: '2017-01',
          events: {
            "2017-01-11": {"number": 5, "url": "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?pli=1#main_7"},
            "2017-01-26": {"number": 1, "url": "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?pli=1#main_7"}, 
            "2017-02-03":{"number": 1}, 
            "2017-02-12": {}}
        });
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```